# Update service configuration setting in Azure using powershell

Tags: azure

I've got a deployment running in Azure.
I need to change one configuration setting of that deployment. What would be the easiest way to do it programmatically using powershell.

Answer (score -2):

Powershell would be better to change the setting, but there are even easier ways to do this:

- Through the portal (this allows you to modify the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg)
- By using [CSRun.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433001.aspx) (this allows you to upload a new ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file)

Comment: portal, of cause, but it is not a convenient option for me.
you can upload ServiceConfiguration file using Cmdlets as well, Set-AzureDeployment [-Config], but it's a maintenance headache for me. I just want to update one setting.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.